# c++, printf wrong output characters

Tags: c++, c, printf, cout

Im writing a c program for an university exam, and im dealing with the following issue: when I try to print the "£" character to the screen with cout or printf, it comes out the "ù" character instead. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your terminal might not support UTF-8 characters.

Comment: If you write a `c` program please dont tag `c++`

Comment: Since there's a grave problem with obtaining animal entrails for divination, we have to resort to asking you to show your code (see [mcve]) and specify which compiler and OS you use. Sorry about the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows the console uses another code page.

Add this to your includes:

```
#include <windows.h>
```

Add this as the first line of your `main` function:

```
SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);
```

**Or a more portable solutiuon:**

Add this to your includes:

```
#include <locale.h>
```

Add this as the first line of your `main` function:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```